# I am confused about repositories

Tags: 20.04, repository

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and, when I open the "applications" application (the checkerboard looking thing in the sidebar) some of the applications have duplicate icons, and, in the case of the Audacity sound editor, clicking on each one brings up an Audacity that behaves differently.
I also have a "software updater" along with a "software and updates" plus a "Ubuntu Software" and; wait, there's more...a "snap store"
Are these different "repositories?" and, when a box pops open saying "Updated software is available for this computer" with install now (or later) is that the way I should be updating; because I can also go to the "software and updates" and it will tell me the sources are out of date, I need an internet connection, and then will go to "refreshing cache" before hanging up, so I have to pull the battery out of the laptop then reboot (because I can't even bring up a terminal to run pgrep and kill)
I prefer to use command lines in a terminal because I'm trying to learn unix and eventually the kernel etc.
Can I run apt-get update; then upgrade and skip all the graphical package managers, which is what I believe the snap store and Ubuntu software is?
I think I have 3 copies of Audacity and they overwrite each other; or they have their config files in different places and I have lost music that I've spent hours on by forgetting which icon opened the program if I have to restart...
I just want a simple way to update, even if I have to do it manually every other day...
livepatch is on, too, confusing me more...thanks for reading this far and for any help; trying to attach a screenshot...

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1252134/) and [How do I remove duplicate entries from Dash on 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157724/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-entries-from-dash-on-18-04)

Comment: Was this an upgrade for an older version?